# Adding RGB channel to the 2D matrix [R]

Tags: r, matrix, multidimensional-array, rgb

Here is an example matrix:

```
mymat <-matrix(runif(24*24), ncol=24)
```

I can plot this matrix using ggplot2, so I can obtain color representation of values:

```
plot_mat <- function(mat){
  mat_df<- reshape2::melt(mat)
  plt <- mat_df %>% ggplot2::ggplot(aes(Var2, Var1)) + geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) +scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c('blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red')) + theme_bw()
  return(plt)
}

plot_mat(mymat)
```

I would like to add RGB channel to my data without converting them into an image. I would like to add another dimension to my mymat, so the dim(mymat) output would look 24, 24, 3. Unfortunately, I do not know, how to do so.

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the colors used in your plot with `ggplot_build()`, they are stored as hex colors, convert it to RGB colors with `col2rgb()` and reshape it using `array()`. If the resulting array is not properly sorted you can fix it likely with transposing `t()` onto the final results or one of the outputs throughout the steps will be enough.

```
set.seed(123) # For reproducibility

mymat <-matrix(runif(24*24), ncol=24) 

plot_mat <- function(mat){
  mat_df<- reshape2::melt(mat)
  plt <- mat_df %>% ggplot2::ggplot(aes(Var2, Var1)) + geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) +scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c('blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red')) + theme_bw()

  pg <- ggplot_build(plt) # Extract data from the plot
  RGBcolors <- col2rgb(pg$data[[1]]$fill, alpha = FALSE) # Transform the fill column to RGB 2D matrix

  RGB_array <- array(t(RGBcolors), c(24,24,3)); # create new array reshaping to 24x24x3
# t() to transpose RGBcolors matrix to fit new third dimension
  RGB_array <- DescTools::Rev(RGB_array, margin=1) # RGB_array  array is flipped
  return(RGB_array)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that the produced RGB array was flipped, so I used DescTools::Rev() function along 1st dim (rows) so now it is as should be.

Comment: Ok, so I edited the post in case someone read this. Did you use like this `RGB array <-DescTools::Rev(RGB array ) ` ?

Comment: I did this: flipped <- DescTools::Rev(RGB_array, margin=1). AFAIK without defining the margin it fully transposes the array. By the way - do you have an idea how to achieve this without melting and using ggplot?

Comment: I don't know :( I've never used melt function. And the trick is taking advantage of ggplot defining the colours. Maybe you can try to get the colors from the specific palet and use a function that define the colors but with an array. But I don't know it.

Comment: I have found a non-ggplot solution. I am posting it as an answer here in case if someone would be interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

After some trials and errors I have found a following non-ggplottish solution:

```
#values in matrix converted to hex colors
colored_mymat <- paintmap::color_matrix(mymat, colors=rainbow(100))
#the rest is the same as in Robertos answer
RGB_mymat <- grDevices::col2rgb(colored_mymat, alpha = FALSE)
ar <- array(t(RGB_mymat), c(24,24,3))

#and this is for plotting purposes
flipped <- DescTools::Rev(ar, margin=1)

#rescaling values in matrix so the image would accept an input
rescaled_mymat <- apply(flipped, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(X) (X - min(X))/diff(range(X)))

numbers_mymat <- unlist(apply(rescaled_mymat, 2, rev))
par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
image(numbers_mymat, useRaster=TRUE, axes=TRUE, col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
```

I hope this might help someone someday.

Comment: Great solution!